# useReducer с useRef или props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Как использовать useRef или props получаемые с запроса в useReducer? Я хочу обновить данные которые уже стоят в defaultValue при нажатие кнопки. При нажатии у меня сначала undefined, а потом правильные данные отправляются только со второго раза. Конечно я могу собрать и без useReducer, но стало интересно.

```
const inputStateReducer = (state, action) => {
    if(action.type === 'INPUT'){
        return {
            email: action.value,
        }
    }
    return {email: state.value}
}
```

```
const CabinetInfo = props => {
  return(
    const [inp, dispatch] = useReducer(inputStateReducer, {
        email: props.data.email
    })

    const submitHandler = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        dispatch({type: 'INPUT', value: inputEmail.current.value})
        console.log(inp)
    }
)
}
```

```
 <input type="email" placeholder="" defaultValue={props.data.email} ref={inputEmail}/>
```

Comment: Что за кнопка? Что она делает? Где копонент, который выводит undifined? Если вы про `submitHandler`, то операция сохранения данных выполняется асинхронно.

Comment: @SwaD из родителя идет fetch запрос и сохраняется в хук, хук передаестя как props data (там данные пользователя). Кнопка формы которая делает submitHandler. Я полазил сейчас, и понял что useReduser сложно использовать с fetch запросами и оно того не стоит обычно.